# styling a list within a list with a class

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, nav

I'm working on an accessible drop down menu and have an example working, however, I can't apply the CSS to all list elements on my site. I successfully added a class to many of the elements, but I'm having trouble with the last three.

Here's my code:

```css
.nav-login {
  background-color: #000;
}

.nav-login a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.nav-login ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-login li {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.nav-login li:hover,
.nav-login li:focus-within {
  background: #990000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-login li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}


/* HELP BELOW */

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li:focus-within>ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-login">
  <li><a href="#">username</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">profile</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Everything with `.nav-login` above works fine... and leaving it off of of the section below the 
`/* HELP BELOW */` comment works. But, I have other `ul` and `li` elements throughout the site and can't have this CSS hide those elements...

How can I add the `nav-login` class to these elements OR how can I specify them for this section?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to change it to this!

```
.nav-login li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon S

As I understand you want to apply the ".nav-login" class you used in the first "ul" tag to the inner "ul" tag, as I can see there is another class that overrides the "nav-login" class of this inner section which is ".nav-login ul". You can see them in the devtool. Let me know if this is helpful or provide some examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Good Luck. 
See screenshots.

[image: First Sceenshot]

[image]